# c++11 : Compare lambda expression

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

Imagine have the following class :

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

template<typename T1> class Signaler
{
public:
  typedef std::function<void (T1)> Func;

public:
  Signaler()
  {
  }

  void Call(T1 arg)
  {
    for(Int32 i = (Int32)_handlers.size() - 1; i > -1; i--)
    {
      Func handler = _handlers[i];
      handler(arg);
    }
  }

  Signaler& operator+=(Func f)
  {
    _handlers.push_back( f );
    return *this;
  }

  Signaler& operator-=(Func f)
  {
    for(auto i = _handlers.begin(); i != _handlers.end(); i++)
    {
      if ( (*i).template target<void (T1)>() == f.template target<void (T1)>() )
      {
        _handlers.erase( i );
        break;
      }
    }

    return *this;
  }

private:
  std::vector<Func> _handlers;
};
```

And I use it the following way :

Signaler Global::Signal_SelectionChanged;

```
class C1
{
public:
    void Register()
    {
        Global::Signal_SelectionChanged   += [&](SelectionChangedEventArgs* e)  { this->selectionChangedEvent_cb(e); };
    }

    void Unregister()
    {
        Global::Signal_SelectionChanged   -= [&](SelectionChangedEventArgs* e)  { this->selectionChangedEvent_cb(e); };
    }

    void selectionChangedEvent_cb(SelectionChangedEventArgs* e) {}
};

class C2
{
public:
    void Register()
    {
        Global::Signal_SelectionChanged   += [&](SelectionChangedEventArgs* e)  { this->selectionChangedEvent_cb(e); };
    }

    void Unregister()
    {
        Global::Signal_SelectionChanged   -= [&](SelectionChangedEventArgs* e)  { this->selectionChangedEvent_cb(e); };
    }

    void selectionChangedEvent_cb(SelectionChangedEventArgs* e) {}
};
```

Now, the problem that I have is when I call 'Unregister' from the class C2, it removes the wrong version of the 'lambda" expression, because the 'lambda' looks similar.

How can I solve this problem ?

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to use some id to unregister? In a signal manager I've made, I store the handlers in a list. The register function returns a list iterator pointing to the new handler. Unregister takes that as a parameter and uses it to delete the handler. Another option would be to use an integer id and store handlers in an int => handler map.

Comment: Targets from two `std::function<T>` can be meaningfully compared in the way you're using, so unless you post some relevant code showing you populating the vector then attempting the delete and results afterwards - so we have a hope of spotting your actual mistake - the question's a waste of time....

Comment: Hi, the code for populating the vector is there !!! See the class C1 & C2, when calling Register/Unregister.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using `std::function::target` with a type that is not the type of the object stored in the `std::function`, so it is returning a null pointer.  That is, you need to know the actual type of the object stored in the `std::function` to be able to call `target`.

Even if you were to call `target` with the lambda closure type used to add the callback, this wouldn't work for two reasons: first, lambda closure types are unique (5.1.2p3) so the `+=` and `-=` lambdas have different types even if they are syntactically identical; second, the closure type for a lambda-expression is not defined to have an `operator==` (5.1.2p3-6, 19-20), so your code would not even compile.

Switching from lambdas to `std::bind` wouldn't help, as bind types are also not defined to have `operator==`.

Instead, consider using an id to register/unregister callbacks.  You could also use your own functor which defines `operator==`, but that would be a lot of work.